# JavaScript OnChange Listener position in HTML markup

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems getting the OnChnage Listener to work, if i position the script after the `</form>` tag the listener works fine but if i place the script within the `<head>` tags it fails to work.

On my site i can only have the script within the `<head>` tags is there anything I can do to make the script runn within the `<head>` tags?

in this configuration the script does not work

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.addEventListener) {
    document.getElementById('address').addEventListener('change', loadXMLDoc, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent){
    document.getElementById('address').attachEvent("onchange", loadXMLDoc);
}

function loadXMLDoc(){
   alert('worked');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>

<input id="address" name="address" type="text"/>
<input id="test" name="test" type="text"/>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it this way:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload= function () {
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById('address').addEventListener('change', loadXMLDoc, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent){
        document.getElementById('address').attachEvent("onchange", loadXMLDoc);
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(){
       alert('worked');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in the `window.onload` function:

```
<head>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if(window.addEventListener) {
            document.getElementById('address').addEventListener('change', loadXMLDoc, false);
        } else if (window.attachEvent){
            document.getElementById('address').attachEvent("onchange", loadXMLDoc);
        }

        function loadXMLDoc(){
            alert('worked');
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you place the script in the `<head>`, the elements you are getting with `document.getElementById` do not exist yet. Wait for the window to load before adding the event listener.

You need to wait for the window to load with a jQuery `$(document).ready` or by adding a loaded listener to the window:

```
window.addEventListener('load',addListener,false);
function addListener() {
    //your code here
}
```