# Create onchange event with javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I've been working on trying to trigger an onchange listener with java script in Mozilla Firefox.  I've found a lot on Stack Overflow posted about this, but nothing seems to be working for my unique case.

I've created this HTML with a onchange listener from an onchange event using this helpful post ([JavaScript OnChange Listener position in HTML markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185266/javascript-onchange-listener-position-in-html-markup)).  Here's my code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload= function () {
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('search-box')[0].addEventListener('change', loadXMLDoc, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent){
        document.getElementsByClassName('search-box')[0].attachEvent("onchange", loadXMLDoc);
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(){
       alert('It worked');
    }
}

function addTextCallListener() {
var searchBox = document.getElementsByClassName("search-box")[0];
searchBox.value = "Hello";
}
</script>
</head>
<BODY>
<input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Search">
<br \>
<button type="button" onclick="addTextCallListener()">Click Me!</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I also saved it as this jsfiddle (for some reason I had to keep it all together for it to work, I couldn't break it up into js and html).
https://jsfiddle.net/josephfedor42/crogL0zd/1/

If you play with this jsfiddle you can see that entering text and pressing enter will trigger the listener and the pop up with the message “It worked” will appear.

But if the button “Click Me!” is pressed it only changes the value of the text box, and the onchange listener is not called.

I realize I could easily add an onchange event to this button.  But I want to to trigger the listener by programatically/ superficially using javascript in my `addTextCallListener()` function.

I've tried the simple stuff, like calling 
`searchBox.onchange();`
`searchBox.focus();`
`searchBox.click();`

And a combination of these to add and remove the focus.  But it doesn't seem to work.  I've found quite a few posts on triggering an onchange event, but nothing that works in Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for that link of a possible duplicated question.  I had checked out that link before.
But I gave it a try again.  I saved the jsfiddle from them both and neither one work.

My implementation of Dorian's answer
https://jsfiddle.net/josephfedor42/zaakd3dj/

My implementation of Alsciende's answer
https://jsfiddle.net/josephfedor42/xhs6L6u2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, I'm looking for a JavaScript only answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: so all you want is to trigger an event manually?

Comment: I am wondering if your question couldn't be trimmed to "Why setting `input.value` doesn't trigger the `change` event in Firefox?" with a small example code, but I'm not sure it is what you want either, so I won't do the edit for you, but please... try to clarify.

Comment: I'm not really interested in why it doesn't trigger the change event.  I want to create the event so the code does what I want.

Comment: hmm bad behavior on your side then... You should try to understand why it doesn't work  in order to make it work. But then @TomSardy's answer gives you a way to trigger the event, even if you shouldn't do it. My comment on my own answer gives you a proper way to achieve what you want : https://jsfiddle.net/crogL0zd/5/

Comment: I don't want to get in a contest of words over which ways are more ethical than others.  I do realize I could easily add an `onclick=` event and make this work.  What I am interested in is finding a different way of doing it.  A way where I trigger the onchange event using JavaScript.

Comment: Down-voters:  I do realize I'm trying to solve a very standard problem, in a very non-conventional way.  But that is my intent.  I want to see if it can be done this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I needed to add to my function addTextCallListener:

```
var evObj = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evObj.initEvent( 'change', true, true );
searchBox.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

I updated the jsfiddle.  The working code is here https://jsfiddle.net/josephfedor42/crogL0zd/7/

Answer (score 1):

<sup>emphasize mine</sup>
According to the mdn page about [the change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change),

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`
>   elements when a change to the element's value is committed **by the
>   user**.

and to [whatwg specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#event-input-change) :

> When the input and change events apply (which is the case for all
>   input controls other than buttons and those with the type attribute in
>   the Hidden state), the events are fired to indicate that **the user has
>   interacted with the control.**

Therefore, setting the value of an input is not an action "committed by the user" nor a sign that "the user has interacted with the control", since it was made by the code.

So, even if the specifications for this event are [kind of unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329566/in-what-authorative-specification-is-the-onchange-event-exhaustively-defined), the event should not fire when you change its value by code.

Comment: So the best practice in your case is just to call the callback you attached to the event inside the `addTextCallListener` function

Comment: I agree that an onchange event should not fire when I change the value of the textbox.  But I want to call the onchange event and do it through JavaScript.  Other user events can be called through JavaScript such as `.click()` which simulates a user clicking on an item on the screen.

Comment: @Joe https://jsfiddle.net/crogL0zd/5/ or if you really want to do something bad : https://jsfiddle.net/crogL0zd/6/

Comment: That is some really good info on the change event.  Thanks Kaiido

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function addTextCallListener() {
    var searchBox = document.getElementsByClassName("search-box")[0];
    searchBox.value = "Hello";

    //fire the event
    if (document.createEvent) {
        searchBox.dispatchEvent('change');
    } else {
        searchBox.fireEvent("onchange");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to fire an already existing event outside of the standards

Comment: @Kaiido: Me neither, that's why the OP question has `-1`. This is just another solution

Comment: Hmm I'm wondering if we shouldn't edit the question with only "why setting `input.value` doesn't trigger the `change` event?"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Tom.  Unfortunately it doesn't work.  I updated my jsfiddle with your code:  https://jsfiddle.net/josephfedor42/crogL0zd/4/

Answer (score -1):

Replace `onchange` with `change` in this part:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('search-box')[0].attachEvent("onchange", loadXMLDoc);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  That was a typo.  I tried changing both to "onchange" and the listener wouldn't even work at all.  "change" is the right one.  That's one piece to this hpuzzle...

Comment: Firefox doesn't know the attachEvent method